# transactions and conditional update in Jooq with scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, transactions, jooq

I'm trying to run this update query:

```
val updatedRows: Int = jooqDSL.dsl update ACCOUNT set(
          ACCOUNT.LOGIN_MEANS, loginMeans.loginType.toString) set(
          ACCOUNT.LOGIN_DATA, loginMeans.loginData) where (
          ACCOUNT.ID equal accountId) execute()
```

but it has to update *only* if I don't already have a record with a different ACCOUNT.ID but  with the same login data & means. I could have ran a search before that to try to find these records if they exist. The problem is that I need this query to be a single transaction.
So I thought about adding a condition to the query - that the query will run only if it doesn't find any other records with the same means/data fields, but I couldn't find any help about how to do it with the DSL and Scala.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Solving this with a constraint.

This would typically be solved in the database with a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE account 
  ADD CONSTRAINT acco_uk_means_data UNIQUE (login_means, login_data)
```

In case the update would produce an existing `(login_means, login_data)` combination, the above statement will throw a constraint violation exception.

#### Solving this with a single query

If a constraint is not an option, then simply add a `NOT EXISTS` predicate:

```scala
val updatedRows: Int = jooqDSL.dsl
   .update(ACCOUNT)
   .set(ACCOUNT.LOGIN_MEANS, loginMeans.loginType.toString)
   .set(ACCOUNT.LOGIN_DATA, loginMeans.loginData)
   .where(ACCOUNT.ID equal accountId)
   .andNotExists(
        selectOne()
       .from(ACCOUNT)
       .where(ACCOUNT.LOGIN_MEANS.equal(loginMeans.loginType.toString))
       .and(ACCOUNT.LOGIN_DATA.equal(loginMeans.loginData))
    )
   .execute()
```

You would probably still add an index on those two columns, though:

```sql
CREATE INDEX acco_i_means_data ON (login_means, login_data)
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas! Didn't think about the constraint solution. Very nice